# Не удалось получить данные о пользователе с помощью токена

Tags: wordpress, ulogin

Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию через соцсети на WP. Попробовал несколько плагинов и везде выдает одну и ту же ошибку при попытке входа через любую соцсеть: "Не удалось получить данные о пользователе с помощью токена".

Сейчас стоит uLogin. Хостинг шаред и доступа к настройкам сервера нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неоднократно использовал плагин [Social Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/) от OneAll. Все работает, доступ к хостингу или серверу не нужен.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то там надо получить апи ключ каждой используемой соцсети?

Comment: Да, там каждую сеть надо настраивать на каждый новый сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Я не специалист именно в вордпрессе, но сам после не особо приятного опыта с другими плагинами (в другой cms) для авторизации через соцсети использую и слышал только хорошие отзывы о библиотеке [HybridAuth](https://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/plugins.html). У неё куча плагинов для фреймворков и cms, в том числе и для вордпресса. Так что если это - вариант, то лучше переходить на HybridAuth. А uLogin как проект судя по их твиттеру и гитхабу сейчас не в самом лучшем состоянии.